# Making an integer not reset after game over

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

**I feel like this should be really simple but I cant find a tutorial to explain it and unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to solve it myself and basically rely on tutorials to learn.

I have a game and if you jump over an object you get a point. Please try to imagine with me if you will, I have set it up so there are two numbers on the screen. One number is in the top right and the other in the top left. As of right now, both numbers get +1 when the player jumps over an object, which is what I want. The problem is, both numbers are reset when the player loses. I want the value in the top left to not reset, and keep being added on to with each point the player gets.

If someone could help me with a simple solution for this I'd be very grateful!!!

Also, I should mention I'm using Swift and Spritekit

Okay I've added some code, hopefully I'm in the right direction..

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//This is the value that I want to remain constant and be stored to defaults
let totalText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Masaaki-Regular")


//So this is where I set up the text in my hud, I want it to persist so instead of setting this value = "0" (like with my normal score) I set it to defaults, right? I get an error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'String'
self.totalText.text = defaults.integerForKey("total")
self.addChild(self.totalText)


//Above this is the function that adds a point to the score when the player jumps over a block
self.total++
defaults.setInteger(total, forKey: "total")
defaults.synchronize()

self.totalText.text = String(self.total)
```

Please help me identify the errors I'm made (I'm sure there are plenty, I'm new to this!)

Comment: Show your code you should take a look at nsuserdefaults

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I've added some code that will hopefully help people understand. I read about NSUserDefaults and tried to apply my knowledge but I'm not sure how well I'm doing.

Comment: just add those classes I have provided to your project and use it as I described. No need to sync

Comment: no need to use self most of the time when coding with Swift. Just try it without it if Xcode complains just let it add it for you

Comment: no need to use self most of the time when coding with Swift. Just try it without it if Xcode complains just let it add it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
self.totalText.text = defaults.integerForKey("total")
```

You're assigning an Integer to a property that takes a String.

You need to convert it. For example:

```
let total = defaults.integerForKey("total")
self.totalText.text = "\(total)"
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron!! Finally got it to work. I'm sure it seems trivial to most experienced coders but I just started a couple weeks ago and this problem was driving me insane. The only thing I had to change in your code was "let total" to "var total" Now that I've seen it working I can definitely apply it to other concepts. Thanks again :)

Comment: I code in Objective-C so I can't speak for Swift but this mistake would definitely cause a warning to show up. It's useful to check those warnings.. don't let them queue up to the point where you stop checking them!